# ColdFusion application caches switch statement

Tags: caching, coldfusion, switch-statement

I'm not familiar with caching in coldfusion, but it seems it's doing somethnig it's not supposed to in my website.
I have only one index page, that uses a big switch statement to determin what cfm files to include, to build my website's pages. No everything works fine, I even have a default case that refers back to the homepage when trying to access a non-existing page.

When I create a new page and try to go to it but in the meantime forgetting I need to add a cfcase first, goes to the defaultcase. If I then create the needed cfcase, it should work, but it has cached the redirect of the last time, the path it followed in the switch/case, so I still get the defaultcase. Even if remove the defaulcase from the code, it still goes there.

Is there anyway to tell coldfusion to stop caching my switch/case. The rest of the content may be chached, no problem, just not the path of the switch/case..

**edit 1**
Here's my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <cfswitch expression="#attributes.fuseaction#">
            <cfcase value="home">
                <cfinclude template="dsp_home.cfm" />
            </cfcase>
            <cfcase value="admin">
                <cfinclude template="admin/dsp_login.cfm" />
            </cfcase>
            <cfdefaultcase>
                <cf_goto fuseaction="home">
            </cfdefaultcase>
        </cfswitch>
    </body>
</html>
```

attributes.fuseaction is a variable that is stored in the url of the requested page, like so: http://www.domain.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/#switch/case-variable#.
cf_goto is a custom tag that gives a 301 code and redirects to the specified page where that variable is home.

When I do what I described above, the headers still give me the 301 error code and de redirect to the default case page. So I'm at a loss what it is that's being cached here.

Comment: Seems unlikely to be caching unless you're setting something into application or session scope.  Can you post your code?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the browser caching your page? What happens if you do a forced refresh in your browser?

Answer (score 2):

CF doesn't cache switch/case logic, so it's a red herring to be looking at that to solve whatever your problem actually is.

Do you - by any chance - have "Trusted Cache" switched on in CFAdmin? If so, you'll need to clear it so your CFM files recompile when they're requested, and your changes will take effect.

Failing that: we need to see your code, as per Duncan's suggestion.

Comment: I added my code in my original post. And I have trusted cache switched off already.

Comment: I'll ditto Adam - CF isn't going to cache stuff like this. What if you output attributes.fuseaction and use a cfabort right before the switch - just to be sure the value is what you think it is. Also, look for spaces fter the value. If your value was admin(space), then it wouldn't run the "admin" case.